# How to create generic interface in d.ts file in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have  a function with declared types, which return a tuple with callback and object:

```
const fn = <T, U>(a: T, b :U) => {
    const inner = (a: T, b: U): Promise<T> => {
        return Promise.resolve(a)
    }

    const obj: { a: T, b : U} = { a, b }

    return [inner, obj]
}
```

Now I want to move all types in separate `d.ts` file and make one "clean" interface:

```
const fn: FuncInterface = (a, b) => {
    const inner = (a, b) => {
        return Promise.resolve(a)
    }

    const obj = { a, b }

    return [inner, obj]
}
```

Possible interface:

```
type Tuple<T, U> = [(a: T, b: U) => Promise<T>, {a: T, b : U}]

interface FuncInterface {
    <T, U>(a: T, b: U): Tuple<T, U>
}
```

but how I can declare types for `a & b parameters` here:

```
...
const inner = (a, b) => {
   return Promise.resolve(a)
}
...
```

since for this example `a` and `b` will be type `any` and not generic `T&U`

Comment: I don't think this idea of "clean" is productive, there is no way to completely keep the types separate form the code in this case. While ts will magically infer that the function is generic and a, and b are of type T and U this magic breaks down when you want to reference the generic type parameters in the body of the function. You could let inference take care of the inner parameters as well but only if you are willing to inline `inner`:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAPDANFAqgPigXigG0AKAQwC5ZMAjKrASgLwAUAnAewFsBLAZ1QwcmAN6VqUGlHoBfALoBYAFDKeAO2AQ2AMzIBjaADE4avQEkNW3QagjlUB1DSZc5Khkn0G7hMmfYcZRllZT0ONT5gKG01KmNTC00dfWhCclomfDw7FSVHKDCIqI4aACsCWygyWihg3Py2CGA4NjVidMlM7Pt8x0bm1qh2bn4IADpGvg5EADcIcgYehxlMEtLFJRkgA